# Problems extracting xml nodes using the xml2 package in R

Tags: r, xml, xpath, xml2

I am trying to extract all of the loc nodes from an XML file that is formatted like the one below:

```
<urlset>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.voa.org</loc>
    <lastmod>2018-09-06T05:00:09-04:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

I've imported it into R using the following code:

```
require(xml2)

doc <- read_xml("<urlset>
                 <url>
                 <loc>http://www.url.org</loc>
                 <lastmod>2018-09-06T05:00:09-04:00</lastmod>
                 <changefreq>always</changefreq>
                 <priority>1.0</priority>
                 </url>
                 </urlset>")
```

If I use the xpath "//*", R successfully extracts all of the nodes:

```
xml_find_all(doc,"//*")

{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] <urlset>\n  <url>\n    <loc>http://www.url.org</loc>\n    <lastmod>20 ...
[2] <url>\n  <loc>http://www.url.org</loc>\n  <lastmod>2018-09-06T05:00:0 ...
[3] <loc>http://www.url.org</loc>
[4] <lastmod>2018-09-06T05:00:09-04:00</lastmod>
[5] <changefreq>always</changefreq>
[6] <priority>1.0</priority>
```

But if I use the xpath "//loc" to isolate all of the loc nodes, I don't get anything:

```
xml_find_all(voa.sites,"//loc")

{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Am I entering the xpath incorrectly? I am really stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `voa.sites` the same thing as `doc`? Your successful `xml_find_all` call was on `doc`.

Comment: Read xml as an HTML and then find the nodes. It will do the job.

Comment: Tested it, as suggested by others, if you run `xml_find_all(doc,"//loc")` the expected node is returned.